# set laravel validator based on usertype

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function register(Request $request){


    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($request->user_type == 1 ){
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'dob' => 'required'
            ]);
    }

    if($request->user_type == 2 ){
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'doctor_practice' => 'required'
            ]);
    }

    // then, if it fails, return the error messages in JSON format
    if ($validator->fails()) {    
        return response()->json($validator->messages(), 401);
    }
```

How can I set the validator based on user type? I did try does not work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add rules array by users type and put rules at last

```
$rules = [
    'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'phone_number' => 'required',
];

if($request->user_type == 1 ){
    $rules['dob'] =  'required';
}else if($request->user_type == 2 ){
    $rules['doctor_practice'] =  'required';
}

$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {    
    return response()->json($validator->messages(), 401);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but spell mistake i did, nevertheless thank you for such support.

Answer (score 1):

It is better and more correctly to use embedded mechanism of validation.

```
$rules = [
    'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'phone_number' => 'required',
    'dob' => 'required_if:user_type,1',
    'doctor_practice' => 'required_if:user_type,2',
];

$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {    
    return response()->json($validator->messages(), 401);
}
```

It is described in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)

> required_if:anotherfield,value,...
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.